# REST API Structure to request multiple items

Tags: api, rest, api-design

I have a REST API that looks something like the below where a person can belong to an organisation (but doesn't have to) and a person has many items. The items may also belong to the organisation instead of the person.

```
/people/:personId
/people/:personId/items
/organisations/:orgId/items
/organisations/:orgId/people/:personId/items
```

There is a scenario where we want to query the items for multiple people within an organisation, what's the correct URL structure to use?

#### Option 1

```
/organisations/:orgId/people/items?personId=1&personId=2
```

#### Option 2

```
/organisations/:orgId/items?personId=1&personId=2
```

#### Option 3

```
/items?personId=1&personId=2
```

Comment: None of your options follow the URL structure above.. , you've lopped off the personId parameter and turned it into a query parameter instead.  did you mean to do this?

Comment: Yes, because I want to query for items that belong to multiple people.

Answer (score 3):

It really doesn't matter that much. Your URL is just a 'unique resource locator' the format you use is up to you. Go with what you are most confortable with and your users will understand.

Having said that I'd go with `?personId=1&personid=2` just because its easy to parse/read

take a look at this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602043/rest-api-best-practice-how-to-accept-as-input-a-list-of-parameter-values)

Comment: Hmm, I think I'd go with something like `?personIDs=1,2,3`

Answer (score 2):

I would possibly do something similar to how Microsoft deals with choosing pages to print. An example of this is:

To show user 3

```
...?show=3
```

To show all users from 10-50

```
...?show=10-50
```

To show user `1 to 3` and `5` and `10 to 20`

```
...?show=1-3,5,10-20
```

It gives complete freedom and can be developed quite easily.

For completeness, I've deviced a simple example in Javascript:

```
var input = "3,4,5,10-20,55".split(',');
var complete = [];

for (var x = 0; x < items.length; x++) {
  var item = input[x];
  if (item.contains("-")) {
    var range = item.split("-");
    for (var i = range[0]; i <= range[1]; i++) {
      complete.push(i);
    }
  } else {
    complete.push(item);
  }
}

console.log(complete); //["3", "4", "5", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "55"]
```

Comment: noice, gonna write some tests for parsing unparsing this.